# how to implement insert query in a dynamic form using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I created a dynamic form for the multiple insertions of data stored in the database, here we have two tables **'kly_shops'**,'**kly_flex_details**'.'**kly_shops**' stored shop details.'**kly_flex_details**' stored flex details.it is a dynamic form for the storage of different flex details in a shop. given below i am using method

```
 $fdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(strtr($this->input->post('FDate'), '/', '-')));
    $tdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(strtr($this->input->post('TDate'), '/', '-')));
   $data=array('shop_name'=>$this->input->post('shopname'),
                 'location'=>$this->input->post('location'),
                'from_date'=>$fdate,
                'to_date'=> $tdate,
                'printing_vendor_id'=>$this->input->post('printvendor'),
                'fixing_vendor_id'=>$this->input->post('fixvendor'),
                'total_amount'=>$this->input->post('Amount'),
                'flex_count'=>$this->input->post('flexcount'));
   $this->Shop_Model->add_shops($data); 
  $insert_id= $this->db->insert_id();

    $newfdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(strtr($this->input->post('bindfdate'), '/', '-')));
    $newtdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(strtr($this->input->post('bindtdate'), '/', '-')));

    $data= array(
        'shop_id'=>$insert_id,
        'type'=>$this->input->post('type'),
        'size'=>$this->input->post('size') ,
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'from_date'=>$newfdate,
        'to_date'=>$newtdate);
        $this->Shop_Model->add_flexes($data);
        $count=count($this->input->post('atype'));
        $type=$this->input->post('atype');
            foreach( $type as $i=>$a)
            // for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
            {

                $frdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(strtr($this->input->post('abindfdate')[$i], '/', '-')));
                $trddate= date('Y-m-d',strtotime(strtr($this->input->post('abindtdate')[$i], '/', '-')));
                $data = array(
                    'shop_id'=>$insert_id,
                    'type'=>$a,
                    'size'=>$this->input->post('asize')[$i] ,
                    'name'=>$this->input->post('aname')[$i],
                    'from_date'=> $frdate,
                    'to_date'=>$trddate
                    );

                $this->Shop_Model->add_flexes($data);

            }
```

insertion method is done properly, but I was getting a database error,that is

```
Error Number: 1048

Column 'shop_name' cannot be null
INSERT INTO `kly_shops` (`shop_name`, `location`, `from_date`, `to_date`, `printing_vendor_id`, `fixing_vendor_id`, `total_amount`, `flex_count`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '1970-01-01', '1970-01-01', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/branding/klth_system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Act_AddProducts() 
{
   $prodnames = $this->input->post( 'prodname' );
   $prodrates = $this->input->post( 'rate' );
    if ( ! empty($prodnames) && ! empty($prodrates) ) 
    {
        foreach ($prodnames as $key => $value ) 
        {
            $data['product_name'] = $value;
            /* make sure product_rate columns is correct i just guess it*/
            $data['product_rate'] = $prodrates[$key];
            $this->ProductModel->add_products($data);
        }

    } 
}
```

Your model add_products should be like this :

```
function add_products($data)
{
   if ( ! empty($data))
   {
      $this->db->insert('tbl_product_master', $data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error Number: 1048 you are getting because you haven't set default value "NULL" for the `shop_name` column.

If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit `DEFAULT NULL` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have not set the default value to null in the database,
go to your table structure and change the default value for the same column to NULL you will not receive this error
See the sample image for reference.

[sampleimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3KI6.png)